# Handling ties in finding index of n th maximum value in R

Tags: r

I am working on a dataframe and trying to find the index of nth maximum value (n varies by a loop), however, in the columns I have tied values and the program throws an error. Below is a sample dataset. I am basically trying to generate a similar dataframe, but with only the index values of all the values in the column vector of the dataframe.

For the output DF, column 1 in the output DF will have index values of elements of Refer_1, so Output_DF[1,1] will have the index for highest value, while Output_DF[10,1] will have the index of lowest value. Below is the input DF.

```
    Input       
1   17         
2   21          
3   13         
4   26          
5   204         
6   36         
7   14          
8   25          
9   45          
10  37          

Output (index values)
5
9
10
6
4
8
2
1
7
3
```

I am currently using which, unlist and partial together to get the indexes, however, I am unable to rectify the error. Note that the ties can occur with any nth maximum value (not necessarily the column maxima).

```
which(Consolidated_data_new[,i]==unlist(sort(Consolidated_data_new[,i],partial=j)[j]))
```

Please note that I want the code to return only one value at a time, and handle the 2nd tied value in the next loop iteration.

Please help solve this.

Regards,

Comment: The question is what you want to do with ties. This is something you need to decide in advance. Also, it is not clear when you say, n varies by loop. Are you trying to find out the row index of maximum for each referee?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your desired output, maybe this helps `library(dplyr);
n <- 3 ; df %>% mutate_each(funs(rank(., ties.method = "first") < n))` when you can set `n` as you wish.

Comment: Sorry about the format earlier, could you guys please take a look at the neater version of input and outputs described above.

Comment: The "Output" looks like you need `order(Input, decreasing = TRUE)`. Maybe, you need to specify something more?

Comment: Yes, Sorry, but I have multiple columns in the input DF. And I want to preserve the order as well, I am only looking for an output DF with the index values for all the values in each column vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

 DT<-structure(list(Refer_1 = c(11L, 15L, 7L, 19L, 104L, 24L, 11L, 
22L, 39L, 19L), Refer_2 = c(17L, 21L, 13L, 25L, 204L, 36L, 14L, 
25L, 45L, 37L)), .Names = c("Refer_1", "Refer_2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000130788>) 

DT[,lapply(.SD, order,decreasing=TRUE)]
    Refer_1 Refer_2
 1:       5       5
 2:       9       9
 3:       6      10
 4:       8       6
 5:       4       4
 6:      10       8
 7:       2       2
 8:       1       1
 9:       7       7
10:       3       3
```

Comment: But I want the indexes for all values in the column vector, and need to break ties between any n th maximum.Metrics' solution wouldn't give me all the values.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example by using `dput(yourdata)`. I still couldn't clearly understand what you are trying to do. I will update the answer if you make the question more clear.

Comment: Metrics, I have uploaded a reproducible dataset now, input is the input DF, output is the output DF. Note that the only thing is input Df will have multiple columns, and so will the output Df, and I need to figure out index for all the n th maximum values in each column of the input DF.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer. This solution is applicable to multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Metrics, this solves the purpose. I shall post a separate question if I run into anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Your comments suggest you are working with a dataframe that has more than one column and that you want an output dataframe that has the results of `order` with decreasing=TRUE applied to every column:

```
> DF[2] <- sample(1:300, 10)
> DF[3] <- sample(1:300, 10)
> DF
   Input  V2 V3
1     17 210  3
2     21  72  4
3     13 263  1
4     26 249  6
5    204 223 10
6     36  83  7
7     14 107  2
8     25 295  5
9     45 198  9
10    37 112  8

> ordDF <- as.data.frame(lapply(DF, order, decreasing=TRUE))
> names(ordDF) <- paste0("res", 1:length(DF) )

> ordDF
   res1 res2 res3
1     5    8    4
2     9    3    9
3    10    4    2
4     6    5    7
5     4    1   10
6     8    9    8
7     2   10    1
8     1    7    6
9     7    6    3
10    3    2    5

> dput(ordDF)
structure(list(res1 = c(5L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
3L), res2 = c(8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 2L), res3 = c(4L, 
9L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 5L)), .Names = c("res1", "res2", 
"res3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```